# How to do the following XPath query?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Basically I'm working with the following XML:

```
<div>
    <div>
    <b>E-mail:</b>
    <span>TheValue</span>
    </div>
    ... and more div tags
</div>
```

Keep in mind that there are lots of different div tags - but only one containing a  tag with the innertext of "E-mail:".

What I want to parse is the value of the span tag where the bold tag equals "E-mail:".

I know I could do something like `("//div//div[contains(@text(), 'E-mail:')].innerText;`

But I would like to do this by checking if the bold tag contains E-Mail and not just the innerText of the whole div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//div/div[b = 'E-mail:']/span/text()
```

however the last `text()` is optional

```
//div/div[b = 'E-mail:']/span
```

would work as well. The former gives you the text node, the latter the `<span>` element.

If they were not wrapped in a `<div>`, but instead just following each other:

```
//b[. = 'E-mail:']/following-sibling::span[1]
```

---

Note that `.innerText` is non-standard. You should use `.textContent` in modern browsers.

Comment: I see.
However shouldn't 

//div/div/[b = 'E-mail:']/span

be 
//div/div[b = 'E-mail:']/span ?
At least that's what works for me.
Then again I use HtmlAgilityPack in C#.

Comment: DAMNIT. Of course it should. Typo. — The HTML Agility Pack has `.innerText` in its API, you're good to use it, then.

Comment: I see - thanks a lot for the help :)
I'm a rookie at XPath so answers like these are great!